# How can I make substitutions only on the parts of the string between < and > in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

For example,

$thisMessage contains:

```
<...>
<request attribs="true" text="this is a message" ...>text here too</request>
</...>
```

The desired output should be,

```
<...>
<request attribs="true" msg="this is a message" ...>text here too</request>
</...>
```

The "text" enclosed within '<' and '>' must be replaced and the text not within '<' '>' should not be touched.

The regex i wrote goes likes this,

```
$thisMessage =~ s/(<[^>]*)(text)([^<]*>)/$1msg$3/gi;
```

This works but, is there a better way of doing this?

-- Edit --
Is it possible to eliminate $1 and $3 from the replace part?

Comment: Thanks SilentGhost, for the formatting

Comment: @Manni,
without using $1 and $3 in the replace text.
Is it possible to do with only $2 ?

Comment: Why do you care if $1 and $3 are there?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to do things with XML. I find [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig) to be much better for this sort of thing since it already knows how to add, delete, or change attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an assumption that your "text" is followed by = and " and make like this:

```
$thisMessage =~ s/text="/msg="/gi;
```

**EDIT**: Also if you are really only replacing XML attribute names, then you shold probably remove the "i" flag as XML attributes names are case-sensative.

**EDIT**: Another version that handles < and >:

```
$thisMessage =~ s/(?<=\<[^<>]+?)text\s*=(?=[^<>]+?>)/msg=/gi;
```

Comment: Single quotes are OK too, and avoid "footext=": `s/\btext=(['"])/msg=$1/g`

Comment: nice thought... 
but the problem is that the program may also have to go through normal text as-well. In that case, when the regex encounters text=", this would fail. So i feel, that checks for '<' and '>' are necessary.

Any ideas using advanced perl regex?

Comment: I have added another version within the answer.

Comment: My perl 5.14 prints "Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex" for your version with ?<=

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my($in) = '<request attribs="true" text="this is a message" ...>text="here too"</request>';

$in =~ s{<[^>]+\Ktext="}{msg="}g;

print $in;
```

produces this:

```
C:\Temp>perl stackoverflow.pl
<request attribs="true" msg="this is a message" ...>text="here too"</request>
C:\Temp>
```

The `\K` is the key -- see Perl's *perlre* page.  Not sure when `\K` was introduced, so you may need a later version of perl; I was using perl 5.10.0

Comment: \K is a Perl 5.10 feature, it tells the substitution operator to not count the part of the string it matched before \K. It's a built-in way to have a variable length lookbehind.